# What should be size of query for creating a view in redshift using java program

Tags: java, amazon-redshift

I am able to create view in redshift with the size of approx 12kb data but when I increased the size of query it terminate and give below error

> java.sql.SQLException: Amazon The server closed the connection.
>       at com.amazon.support.channels.TLSSocketChannel.read(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: com.amazon.support.exceptions.GeneralException: Amazon The server closed the connection.
>       ... 1 more.

Can anybody tell me if there is any limitation in java to send number of queries to database or any property is there after adding it should we able to run it.

Answer (score 0):

[Redshift limits are documented here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/amazon-redshift-limits.html). The ones relevant for you:

> The number of concurrent user connections that can be made to a cluster is 500.
>
> A workload management (WLM) configuration can define a total concurrency level of 50 for all user-defined queues. For more information, see Defining Query Queues in the Amazon Redshift Database Developer Guide.

If there are more queries than the concurrency level, then the queries wait in a queue to be processed.

So unless you have 500 user connections I don't expect that your connection issues are a result of the number of queries sent to the database.